# Is calling a private function from a public function good coding practice?

Tags: c++, class, binary-search-tree, access-control, function-call

I'm wondering if calling a private function from a public function to achieve a cleaner syntax could cause any type of problems.

```
#include<iostream>

class tree{
    private:
    struct node {
        int data;
        int counter = 1;
        node* left;
        node* right;
    };
    
    node* getnewnode(int x) {
        node* temp = new node();
        temp -> data = x;
        temp -> left = NULL;
        temp -> right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    node* recursiveinsert(int x, node* rootPtr) {// recursively insert a new node
        if(rootPtr==NULL) { // if the tree is empty, append the new node
            rootPtr = getnewnode(x);
        } 
        else if(x <= rootPtr->data){ // if x is lesser than the node value, make a recursive call with the left subtree as root
            rootPtr -> left = recursiveinsert(x, rootPtr -> left);
        }
        else { //if x is greater than the node value, make a recursive call with the right subtree as root
            rootPtr -> right = recursiveinsert(x, rootPtr -> right);
        }
        return rootPtr;
    }

    public:

    //store address of root node
    node* root = NULL;

    void insert(int x) {
        root = recursiveinsert(x, root);
    }
};
```

Using the tree class, instead of calling in main:

```
int main(){
    tree t;
    t.root = t.recursiveinsert(10, t.root);
}
```

I thought it'd be cleaner to call this instead:

```
int main(){
    tree t;
    t.insert(10);
}
```

Is this a good coding practice?

Comment: yes it is. Otherwise how would you call private functions? Its always good practice to extract code from public methods into private ones.

Comment: I don't agree with "Its always good practice to extract code from public methods into private ones.", functions should be separate by what they do, not their accessibility.

Comment: @Riccardo It is a bad practice to declare the pointer root as public.:)

Comment: Muhuhahahaha! `delete mytree.root;`! All your base are belong to us!

Comment: FYI, if you declare the `node` struct outside of the `tree` class, you can reuse it for other purposes. :-)

Comment: Is there a typo? Should the 2/3 snippet have `recursiveinsert`?

Comment: And if you keep doing what you are doing and hide `node`, you have better encapsulation. Pick whichever option makes better sense for your use case.

Comment: @appleapple yes thats a good point. thx for mention it

Comment: How would you (want to) call private methods if it was not from public method?

Comment: @Quimby yes, it was a typo, thanks for making me notice :)

Comment: Ca you name a circumstance in which you would want to have `private` function that is not called - directly or indirectly - by a `public` (or `protected`) function?

Comment: @Peter i can't and you're right! i was probably just overthinking things :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For starters the data member

```
node* root = NULL;
```

shall not be public.

Secondly the function `recursiveinsert` should be declared at least as a static member function.

It is better to declare and define it like

```
static void recursiveinsert( node * &rootPtr, int x ) 
{
    if ( rootPtr == nullptr ) 
    {
        rootPtr = getnewnode(x);
    } 
    else if ( x < rootPtr->data )
    {
        recursiveinsert( rootPtr -> left, x );
    }
    else 
    {
        recursiveinsert( rootPtr -> right, x );
    }
}
```

There is nothing wrong to call a private member function from a public member function. For example it is not rare when a constructor of a class calls a private member function in its mem-initializer list.

The function `getnewnode` can look simpler. For example

```
node* getnewnode( int x)  
{
    return new node { x, 1, nullptr, nullptr };
}
```

Comment: "For example it is not rare when a constructor of a class calls a private member function in its mem-initializer list" Can of worms opened right there. You might need to add more details on this, especially if the private function is virtual and a child class implements it.

Comment: `getnewnode()` should be the constructor for `node` and then you write `new node(x);`.

Comment: With your changes I really want to change `recursiveinsert` to `public: void insert(int x, node *&rootPtr = root) { ... }`. Except default arguments can't be non-static data members. :(

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It is a bad idea to refer to private data member and declare the function as a non-static member function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't think it's a bad idea. It's simply not legal C++ code.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I have not understood what is wrong with the answer?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There is nothing wrong with the answer. I just wish one could combine the public `insert` and private `recursveinsert` into a single function with private default argument.

Answer (score -1):

You would probably also want to hide the 'root' member so that setting it directly wouldn't even be possible. Then have an accessor like:

```
const node * GetRoot () { return node; }
```

Comment: Great advice, although I don't think this is really an _answer_ to the question.

Comment: Returning the root's not all that useful if the root's type isn't accessible. I'd hide `root` away and keep it completely hidden. All interaction with the nodes in the tree should be done by the tree.

Comment: The whole reason for the `tree` class to exist is to hide the `root` node. Otherwise all the operations could be methods of the `node` class.